# React site - On Refresh, Auth Route does not have access to auth context data

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I have my React application working pretty well with authentication using a session cookie from Node Express.  Then on refresh, I got logged out.  So I added a function to my top level App.js to check if the user is logged in and valid.  That worked great.  Then I added a custom AuthRoute to my application.  It checks the auth context to see if the user is authenticated or not.  On refresh, it does not see the updated auth context and kicks the user back to the login.
Here is my AuthRoute.js:

```js
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { NonAuthRoutes } from '../config/AuthRoutesLogic';
import { useGlobalAuthContext } from '../context/authContext';

const AuthRoute = ({
    Component,
    path,
    exact = false,
    requiredRoles
}) => {
    const isAuthed = !!useGlobalAuthContext().user.email;
    console.log({ isAuthed });
    console.log(useGlobalAuthContext().user);

    const userRole = useGlobalAuthContext().user.type;
    const userHasRequiredRole = requiredRoles.includes(userRole);
    console.log(userRole, userHasRequiredRole);
    const message = 'Please log in to view this page';
    return (
        <Route
            exact={exact}
            path={path}
            render={(props) =>
                isAuthed && userHasRequiredRole ? (
                    <Component {...props} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            // pathname: userHasRequiredRole
                            //  ? NonAuthRoutes.login
                            //  : NonAuthRoutes.unauthorized,
                            pathname: NonAuthRoutes.login,
                            state: {
                                message,
                                requestedPath: path
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                )
            }
        />
    );
};

export default AuthRoute;
```

And here is my function from my App.js that runs on refresh to verify the user:

```js
const checkForLoggedInUser = () => {
        axios.get(baseURL + '/users/user').then((res) => {
            console.log({ res });
            if (res.data.user) {
                console.log('there is a logged in user!');
                setAuthData((prevState) => {
                    return {
                        ...prevState,
                        loading: false,
                        user: {
                            email: res.data.user.email,
                            type: res.data.user.type,
                            customer: res.data.user.customer
                        }
                    };
                });
            } else {
                // we have no valid logged in user
                console.log('no logged in user!');
                setAuthData((prevState) => {
                    return {
                        ...prevState,
                        loading: false,
                        user: {
                            email: '',
                            type: '',
                            customer: ''
                        }
                    };
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

**To sum it up:** The cookie persists. The user is still logged in. AuthRoute.js is just kicking them back to login page because `isAuthed` is false.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will depend on how you've configured the server/authentication.

Clearly its working when it receives from the /user endpoint, which makes me think the issue is with the session cookie staying set between refresh.

Open your devtools to the application tab and find the cookie thats set when you hit the `/user` endpoint. Reload and confirm it persists, if not then you have your root cause, this might be because the domains don't match/secure cookie on non https/expiry time on the cookie etc. might be worth providing a codesandbox/repo link if possible.

Comment: The cookie persists.  The user is still logged in.  AuthRoute.js is just kicking them back to login page because `isAuthed` is false.

Comment: Then I'd assume its because the request hasn't had time to return before the components are rendering, and so it goes to the redirect. isAuthed is set based on whether email is set in the context, which seems to only be set on the return from the api, so it'll be undefined on page refresh. When the user auths I would persist the basic user state (nothing sensitive like password), that way on load you'll be auth'd from previous session, and then you clear your local storage (you'll want to ensure isAuthed is then set to false) if the api returns that the user session has expired.

Comment: Interesting, so you're saying throw something like the email into localstorage on user login?  Then in my checkForLoggedInUser function, if not valid user, clear the localstorage as well as the context state?

Comment: Essentially yes, you either need to delay rendering the routes, or you need some source of the required data on that first render after logging in, otherwise the first render of your context will always container undefined (because the http request is async and won't have had time to return yet, and thus set the context). If you dont have any data on the screen that requires the email or whatever you could just use a boolean, and your isAuthed can check for that existing (best practice would be on the server to generate some kind of auth token, but im focusing on the error with the react now)